# Flask SQL: foreign keys and OnUpdate

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

I have three SQL tables. Two are independent of each other and third that will have 2 columns (among others) each with relevant id from the first two tables

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()
import datetime

class Dad(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "dad"
    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    children = db.relationship('Children', backref='dad', lazy='dynamic')

class Mom(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "mom"
    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    children = db.relationship('Children', backref='mom', lazy='dynamic')

class Children(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "children"
    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    dad_name = db.Column(db.String)
    mom_name = db.Column(db.String)
    dad_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('dad.id'))
    mom_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('mom.id'))
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime(6), default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    updated_at= db.Column(db.DateTime(6), default=datetime.datetime.utcnow, onupdate=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
```

I have 2 issues that I need help with

1. If I do `dad.children.append({'name':'Joe', 'dad_name':'Bill', 'mom_name':'Samantha'})` it attaches the `dad.id` automatically but not the `mom.id`. I want it to attach `mom.id` as well based on her name even if I create it from dad.
2. When I try to update the record from pgAdmin, it should update the updated_at column with the update time but it doesn't.

Thanks!